# AWK code to remove rows integer or 0.5 decimal

Tags: awk

I have a list of coordinates with fixed Lon and vary Lat like this:

```
75.5    36.5    37.4290504456
75.5    36.4    52.4753456116
75.5    36.3    66.4775466919
75.5    36.2    84.0023193359
75.5    36.1    111.997085571
75.5    36  172.343933105
75.5    35.9    111.806427002
75.5    35.8    83.5655899048
75.5    35.7    65.6402206421
75.5    35.6    50.8337936401
75.5    35.5    33.7828178406
```

But I would like to remove all rows where lat are integer or a number with 0.5 to have something like this:

```
75.5    36.4    52.4753456116
75.5    36.3    66.4775466919
75.5    36.2    84.0023193359
75.5    36.1    111.997085571
75.5    35.9    111.806427002
75.5    35.8    83.5655899048
75.5    35.7    65.6402206421
75.5    35.6    50.8337936401
```

(I removed 36.5, 36 and 35.5)

How can I do this using awk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's integers or .5s (special case), you can use `$2` modulo 0.5:

```
$ awk '$2%0.5' file

75.5    36.4    52.4753456116
75.5    36.3    66.4775466919
75.5    36.2    84.0023193359
75.5    36.1    111.997085571
75.5    35.9    111.806427002
75.5    35.8    83.5655899048
75.5    35.7    65.6402206421
75.5    35.6    50.8337936401
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Lat always has just one digit after `.`:

```
awk '$2~/\.[^5]/' file
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!
Booth codes worked for me and I have to do the same for a list of vary Lon (I just changed to $1 and worked as well)